# Since installing Windows 10 Creators Update (version 1703), history dialog in Run command not storing previous searches

Tags: windows-10, run-dialog, windows-10-v1703

There is a similar post to this but does not work with my system. The previous suggestion was to turn on `Start > Settings > Personalisation > Start > Show most used apps`. Unfortunately, that option is set to `Off` and greyed out.

`HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU` does not show the list either. it is empty.

I was running Windows 10 version 1703, and recently updated to the Redstone 3 Preview build 16170.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like there is a Group Policy affecting those settings, so I would open **gpedit.msc** and check.  The one you specifically referenced that impacts `Show most used apps` can be found at `User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Start Menu and Taskbar > Remove frequent programs list from Start Menu`.  While you are in there, you should also double-check the settings on `Clear history of recently opened documents on exit` as well as `Do not keep history of recently opened documents`.

Comment: See also:  [Run History (RunMRU) Not Saved in Windows 10?](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/run-mru-history-not-saved-windows/)

Answer (score 1):

OK problem solved, they moved the activator.

It is now at Settings> Privacy> General> Let Windows track App Launches which has to be On.

Comment: Did this problem appear after you installed the Windows 10 Creators Update (version 1703)?

Comment: No, it was there before, but still there in 170331-1532. It is not a Group Policy problem.

Comment: Nigel, are you sure?  Exactly which version of Windows 10 are you using?  Currently, my home network is running Windows 10 Pro on three different machines.  They are all running [the latest version](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-info.aspx) of the Anniversary Update, which is `version 1607 build 14393.1066`.  As you can see in [this screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjzhA.jpg), none of them have the option to `Let Windows track App Launches`... but I have seen screen shots of the Windows 10 Creators Update (version 1703) that do.

Comment: I'm on Build 16170.rs_prerelease.170331-1532. which came through as a new incremental build on April 9th.

Comment: In other words, you are actually on an Insider Preview version of [Redstone 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_history#Redstone_3).  There is certainly nothing wrong with that, but ultimately this solution is confined to certain versions of Windows 10 that were *not* released to the general public when you originally asked the question.  The reason you can say that *"it was there before"* is because you also had Windows 10 version 1703 before it was released, and were recently upgraded to build 16170

Comment: The bottom line is that this information makes a **big** difference in both your question as well as any potential answers, and it really should have been included within your original post.  My initial answer was correct for the mainstream version of Windows 10 (version 1607) at that point in time, but definitely not for an Insider Preview version.  I can help you modify your question so that it accurately reflects those circumstances.